# Using field [year] in calculated column issue

Tags: 2007, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have an issue with the calculated field.

Basically in SharePoint 2007 I have my field called Year, so this Year I would like to use in another calculated field.

So I create the field and put there the following formula:
=[Year]

I save it, and next time I open this column i see => =Year

This means that SharePoint sees [Year] as a function Year :/ it is so stupid, anyone know how to specify that this should be seen as a field and not function.

I dont have issues with other of my fields :/

Answer (score 2):

Since its SharePoint internal name, you should think of alternative name..

If its your development environment, I will suggest you add a column with different name let's say "CompanyYear", and than change the Display Name of the column back to "Year"

In calculated columns you will refer it to as "CompanyYear"